# Remote Config iptables with Python Script

Tags: python, iptables

I knew there's lib called python-iptables.
but it seems that it only support on local machine?
What if i want to remote access a machine and config it's iptables?
Is there any better way to do this kind of automation instead of ssh it and parsing output from executing command line.

Comment: If there is only one node on which you would like to make change then you could either build RPC or if you are looking to use genric one then use configuration management tool like chef, puppet, ansible  ( prefered one) . It will give you power to modify the configuration on remote node

Comment: Thanks!! But still got some questions about RPC !!! let's say there's a target B i want to config, and i have a local machine called A, so i build up a service called "Ip change" on A , then i expose my function to B through RPC????? if that's what i say i think using python-iptables won't work

Comment: 1) target should have functional block of operation where we could have input pramaters
2) dependencies should be available on target machine
3) source should be calling functional RPC with paramters
4) there are no requirement for having module availability at source